# SelectAll checkbox should get unchecked when move to next page in table

Tags: datatables

I am using datatable using jquery to check and uncheck the check box.Everthing is working fine but when i am moving to next page in table (Suppose i have 50 records in table and showing 10 records in one page) then everything is unchecked but selectAll option is still checked . I want it should also not to be checked. When moving to next page it should take as a fresh page.

I am using drawCallback function of dataTable. If you don't use this function then on click of selectAll it will select all the data of each page . After using this functiion i able to select only data on same page but select all still showing in all page.

Comment: Are you using server-side processing? Please provide some more information and code, maybe an executable minimal example.

Comment: yes server side processing

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are currently using for the datatable. Even better would be a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

below code can helps you...

```
$(document).on('click' , '.paginate_button' , function(){
    $('#select_all').prop('checked' , false);
})
```

In this example .paginate_button is a class of pagination and #select_all is a main table heading checkbox id

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).